# JScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have JScript method that is :

```
function init() {
     var userid = System.Environment.getEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
     setUserName(userid);
    }
```

When I debug it , at first line of the init function, I'll get "javascript Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'System' is undefined".

I'd be thankful if some one let me know how can I solve it.

Comment: I have never seen the `System` class in javascript, what are you trying to do? Is this from a third-party library? Can you give more information of what you are working with?

Comment: It looks like JScript allows for a System global, but in the MSDN docs it's not really used in raw JavaScript/Web apps. Can you include a bit more background on this?

Comment: Looks like `System.Environment.getEnvironmentVariable` is a method in the .NET framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx -- perhaps JScript can be used in that environment? I think we need more information about the context you're making this call in.

Comment: If `System.Environment.getEnvironmentVariable` is a method in the .NET framework, then this isn't javascript, its JScript. Which are completely different. JScript is Microsoft and I believe Javascript is Netscape

Comment: I have Silverlight application and I need to send UserName as a parameter from web app to Silverlight App . In Silverlight 3 , we have to use Object tag, and System.Environment.getEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") is the only way that I have found in internet for sendening dynamic parameter to Silverlight. I want to set the UserName in HiddenField and get it in Silverlight app by using  
HtmlElement elm = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("corpID");
string userID = elm.GetAttribute("value");

here is the link:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/149923/355636.aspx

Comment: @artlung, @Anthony Forloney: The `System` namespace is provided to Windows Desktop Gadgets by the host (sidebar.exe).  WD Gadgets are coded in HTML/JScript, which is probably how he picked up this source code from somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using code specific to Windows Sidebar/Desktop Gadgets.  The host for Windows Desktop Gadgets provides the `System` namespace for access to computer properties that are not normally available to Javascript.

Gadgets can be coded in Javascript which is most likely how you picked up that source code.  Using this namespace outside of a Windows Desktop Gadget (ie in a web page or shell script) wouldn't work because it is provided by the host (sidebar.exe).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723688(VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

One note here to anyone trying to resolve the same error in typescript: when using module type "System" in an ASP.NET project, you may encounter the very same error. Change "compilerOptions": { "module": "System" } in the tsconfig.json to any other module type. When set to system, the first line in all .js files will include a reference to System.register() which cant be found, hence this error.